# multi-sub-domain cookies and ajax problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, cross-domain

I need an `HttpOnly` authentication cookie to work on:

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com
abc.mydomain.com
```

so that I can be logged into all three places via a single login.

This is working fine, by setting my cookie domain to:

```
.mydomain.com
```

here is the response header that sets the cookie:

```
MYAUTHCOOKIE=FOO; domain=.mydomain.com; path=/; HttpOnly
```

This all works fine for normal browser requests.

However, I need to make an AJAX request from `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` to `abc.mydomain.com`.

When I make the request, it isn't passing the authentication cookie. Why is this, and what can i do about it?

If i make a request to the same host as the page the JS resides on, it does send the cookie :s

Here's my request code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST"
    , data: { data: { foo: bar} }
    , dataType: "json"
    , url: "http://abc.mydomain.com/foo"
    , timeout: 5000
    , success: function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('woo!');
    }
    , error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert('meh');
    }
});
```

Is this some cross domain policy? Why doesnt the cookie domain make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), subdomains are indeed "hostile" to your top domain, but it can be fixed by setting document.domain (same article).

Comment: If you set document.domain to 'foo.com' on URL http://one.foo.com/, how does the server know the document.domain setting on http://two.foo.com/ before it makes the request to 'two'?

Comment: How would making CORS requests with access-control headers affect this situation?